# EOF Error in python code for USACO problem revegetate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on a USACO problem and I have this code so far:

```
fin = open('revegetate.in', 'r')
fout = open('revegetate.out', 'w')

pasture_num, cow_num = map(int, input().split())
pastures = []
ans = [1] * pasture_num

for _ in range(cow_num):
    past1, past2 = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
    pastures.append([past1 - 1, past2 - 1])

pastures.sort()
for a, b in pastures:
    if ans[a] == ans[b]:
        ans[b] += 1

        for i, j in pastures[:pastures.index([a, b])]:
            if ans[i] == ans[j]:
                ans[b] += 1
print(''.join(map(str, and)))
```

Although when I run it, it returns a EOF error on line 4:

```
pasture_num, cow_num = map(int, input().split())
```

sample input would be:

```
5 6
4 1
4 2
4 3
2 5
1 2
1 5
```

How do I fix this EOF error?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing it to fin.readline() instead of input().